# How to subscribe to an event in a child usercontrol in Silverlight?

Tags: silverlight

I've got a usercontrol (MyUC) that is programatically added to a page (MainPage) several times.

In MyUC I set the DataContext to a view model like this:

```
    private void UserControl_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        DataContext = new MyUCViewModel();
    }
```

In my view model (MyUCViewModel) I have a collection of data items:

```
    public MyDataItemCollection MyDataItems { get; private set; }
```

And in the constructor I have:

```
    public MyUCViewModel()
    {
        this.MyDataItems = new MyDataItemCollection();
        this.MyDataItems.ChosenItems.CollectionChanged += new NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler(ChosenItemsChanged);

        this.MyDataItems.Add(new DataItem());
    }
```

From the above MyDataItems has another collection in it for ChosenItems and I added a NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler to it.

Other parts of my code add and remove from the ChosenItems collection and that part seems to work ok.

Next I have the event handler method in the view model:

```
    private void ChosenItemsChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Chosen Items Changed");
    }
```

This also works and I get a messagebox everytime the user makes a change in the UI that affects the ChosenItems collection.

The part I'm trying to figure out now is how do I set it up so that my MainPage does something when the ChosenItemsChanged event fires in my user controls.  What I want to do is have the MainPage loop through the generated MyUC controls on the page and make each usercontrol call a method.

Comment: I do not understand the problem. What event are you wanting to *subscribe to* or method are you *wanting to call* on the child controls (presumably the DataItem class)? Your title and description seem to be conflicting. Can you please clarify?

Comment: I have a usercontrol with a viewmodel that I add to MainPage and from that usercontrol's viewmodel I want to run a method in MainPage when something happens in my usercontrol.  In this case ChosenItemsChanged is in my usercontrol's viewmodel and I want to do something in MainPage when ChosenItemsChanged is fired.  I'm not sure if "subscribe" was the best term to use, but that is what I've read people describe it as.

Answer (score 1):

You can add more event listeners in the MainPage like this:

```
MyUCViewModel viewModel = myUC.DataContext;
viewModel.MyDataItems.ChosenItems.CollectionChanged 
  += new NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler(MainPage_ChosenItemsChanged);
```

Answer (score 1):

*This is based on the comment as the question was a little misleading:*

While not strictly MVVM, as your question appears to be, your should write your User Controls as if it was a third-party control and simply expose a custom event on it. User Controls should always be a black-box with a public interface. For a reusable control that is self-contained (as many are) MVVM is overkill.

### e.g.

in your User Control add:

`public event EventHandler<MyEventArgs> MyEvent`

Create a `MyEventArgs` class deriving from `EventArgs` and get it to hold useful parameters (like the selected item).

In your main page add a handler to `MyEvent` on each User Control you dynamically add.

*I actually think the MVVM model is flawed and all this sort of controlling logic and event handlers belong in a `Controller` class (MVCVM!), but that's another story.* :)